# Finding the ideal B-spline through data points using Euler-Lagrange: is it just too hard to do?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, euler-lagrange-equation, arc-length, bezier-curve

I am not even sure I have a question anymore (I will just give up)... in the past month or so I have been researching cubic Bézier curves. The idea was to find a fit through data points, using piecewise Bézier curves and the Euler-Lagrange equation to minimize an "energy" proportional with the square of the length of the (total) curve (elastic energy used to stretch) plus the integral of the square of the curvature $\kappa$ of the curve (energy required to bend the curve).

Edit: it took me three whole days to type this "question". Please don't get mad for wasting your time if you choose to read it.

Here is what I have done so far with respect to the length of the curve.

Let
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}\vec{P}(t) &= (1-t)^3 \vec{P_0} + 3(1-t)^2t \vec{C_0} + 3(1-t)t^2 \vec{C_1} + t^3 \vec{P_1} \\
&= \vec{P_0} + 3(\vec{C_0} - \vec{P_0})t + 3(\vec{C_1} - 2\vec{C_0} + \vec{P_0})t² + (\vec{P_1} - 3\vec{C_1} + 3\vec{C_0} - \vec{P_0})t³\end{aligned} \end{equation}\tag{1}$$
be a cubic Bézier curve defined by its begin and end points $\vec{P_0}$ and $\vec{P_1}$, and control points $\vec{C_0}$ and $\vec{C_1}$.

Instead of $\{\vec{P_0}, \vec{C_0}, \vec{C_1}, \vec{P_1}\}$ to define the curve, lets use $\{\vec{B}, \vec{V}, \vec{A}, \vec{J}\}$ where
$$\begin{align}\vec{B}&=\vec{P_0} \\
\vec{V}&=3(\vec{C_0} - \vec{P_0}) \\
\vec{A}&=6((\vec{C_1} - \vec{P_0}) - 2(\vec{C_0} - \vec{P_0})) \\
\vec{J}&=6((\vec{P_1} - \vec{P_0}) - 3(\vec{C_1} - \vec{C_0}))\end{align} \tag{2}$$

This is not random, you will thank me later; the idea behind it is that the coefficients other than the constant term represent the velocity, acceleration and jerk (if $t$ was "time") with respect to $t$, which only depends on the *shape* of the curve, not its position. Therefore those coefficients should be expressed in terms of differences between any two of $\{\vec{P_0}, \vec{C_0}, \vec{C_1}, \vec{P_1}\}$.

Substituting this into $(1)$ gives,
$$\vec{P}(t) = \vec{B} + \vec{V}t + \frac{1}{2}\vec{A}t^2 + \frac{1}{6}\vec{J}t^3 \tag{3}$$

Then the chord length of the curve between $\vec{P_0}$ and $\vec{P_1}$ is given by
$$chord\_length = \int_0^1 \lVert \vec{P'}(t) \rVert \,dt \tag{4}$$
where $\vec{P'}(t)$ is the derivative of $\vec{P}(t)$ with respect to $t$, also called the `velocity`:
$$\vec{P'}(t) = \vec{V} + \vec{A}t + \frac{1}{2}\vec{J}t^2 \tag{5}$$

In order to calculate the norm $\lVert \vec{P'}(t) \rVert$ we can take the square root of the dot product with itself:
$$\lVert \vec{P'}(t) \rVert = \sqrt{\vec{P'}(t) \cdot \vec{P'}(t)} \tag{6}$$

Working out this dot product we get a fourth degree polynomial in $t$:
$$\vec{P'}(t) \cdot \vec{P'}(t) = c_4 t^4 + c_3 t^3 + c_2 t^2 + c_1 t + c_0 \tag{7}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}c_0 &= \lVert \vec{V} \rVert^2 \\
c_1 &= 2 (\vec{V} \cdot \vec{A}) \\
c_2 &= \vec{V} \cdot \vec{J} + \lVert \vec{A} \rVert^2 \\
c_3 &= \vec{A} \cdot \vec{J} \\
c_4 &= \frac{1}{4}\lVert \vec{J} \rVert^2\end{aligned} \tag{8}$$

Note how all of this holds for vectors of dimension two *or more*. We're not talking about $x$ and $y$ or whatever.

We might also be interested in a polynomial in $u$ after a substitution $t = u + s$, where we'll integrate from $u=-s$ to $u=-s+1$. After substitution we end up with:
$$\begin{align}chord\_length &= \int_{-s}^{-s+1} \sqrt{c_4' u^4 + c_3' u^3 + c_2' u^2 + c_1' u + c_0'} \space \,du \\
&= \sqrt{c_0'} \int_{-s}^{-s+1} \sqrt{\frac{c_4'}{c_0'}u^4 + \frac{c_3'}{c_0'}u^3 + \frac{c_2'}{c_0'} u^2 + \frac{c_1'}{c_0'} + 1}\space\space \,du \end{align} \tag{9}$$

where
$$\begin{aligned}c_0' &= c_0 + c_1 s + c_2 s^2 + c_3 s^3 + c_4 s^4 \\
c_1' &= c_1 + 2 c_2 s + 3 c_3 s^2 + 4 c_4 s^3 \\
c_2' &= c_2 + 3 c_3 s + 6 c_4 s^2 \\
c_3' &= c_3 + 4 c_4 s \\
c_4' &= c_4\end{aligned} \tag{10}$$

Let
$$\begin{aligned}d_1 &= \frac{c_1'}{c_0'} \\
d_2 &= \frac{c_2'}{c_0'} \\
d_3 &= \frac{c_3'}{c_0'} \\
d_4 &= \frac{c_4'}{c_0'}\end{aligned} \tag{11}$$

So that the problem of finding the chord length becomes integration of $\sqrt{1 + d_1 u + d_2 u^2 + d_3 u^3 + d_4 u^4}$.

Since there is no known algebraic expression for that, we can proceed by finding the Taylor series of this square root around $u=0$ ($t=s$). Lets write
$$\sqrt{1 + d_1 u + d_2 u^2 + d_3 u^3 + d_4 u^4} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}g_n u^n \tag{12}$$

then the following recursive relationship for the $g_n$ can be found (with three days of hard work):
$$\begin{aligned}
g_1 &= +\frac{1}{2}d_1 \\
g_2 &= -\frac{1}{2}d_1 g_1 + \frac{1}{1}d_2 \\
g_3 &= -\frac{3}{4}d_1 g_2 - \frac{0}{1}d_2 g_1 + \frac{3}{2}d_3 \\
g_4 &= -\frac{5}{6}d_1 g_3 - \frac{1}{2}d_2 g_2 + \frac{1}{2}d_3 g_1 + \frac{2}{1}d_4 \\
g_5 &= -\frac{7}{8}d_1 g_4 - \frac{2}{3}d_2 g_3 - \frac{1}{4}d_3 g_2 + \frac{1}{1}d_4 g_1 \\ 
&\space\space\vdots \notag \\
g_n &= -\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}d_1 g_{n-1} - \frac{n-3}{n-2}d_2 g_{n-2} - \frac{2n-9}{2n-6}d_3 g_{n-3} - \frac{n-6}{n-4}d_4 g_{n-4}\end{aligned} \tag{13}$$

This Taylor series should converge if $u$ is close enough to zero. In fact, it turns out that for tame curves where, say the deviation from a straight line is less than a third of the distance between $\vec{P_0}$ and $\vec{P_1}$, one can calculate the chord length with a single integral taking $s=1/2$ and integrating from $-1/2$ to $+1/2$. Otherwise we might have to do it piecewise and add up a few chord length pieces. For example one could pick six pieces where $s$ is one of $\{\frac{1}{12}, \frac{3}{12}, \frac{5}{12}, \frac{7}{12}, \frac{9}{12}, \frac{11}{12} \}$ and then integrate (six times) from $-\frac{1}{12}$ to $+\frac{1}{12}$. Thus, in general we are interested in obtaining the integral between $-\delta$ and $+\delta$ where $\delta$ is some fixed, positive real less than or equal $1/2$.

Combining equation $(9)$ through $(13)$ we can write,
$$chord\_length\_piece = \sqrt{c_0'} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}g_n u^n\right)\,du \tag{14}$$

Assuming $\delta$ is small enough that the sum converges, we can swap the sum and integration and get
$$chord\_length\_piece = 2\delta\sqrt{c_0'} \left( 1 + \sum_{even\ n\geq 2}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^n}{n(n+1)}g_n \right) \tag{15}$$

Note that only the $g_n$ for even $n$ are left because the odd ones cancel. For example $\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} g_1 u\,du = \left[\frac{1}{2}g_1u^2\right]_{-\delta}^{\delta} = \frac{1}{2}g_1\delta^2 - \frac{1}{2}g_1(-\delta)^2 = 0$. The other terms are doubled, hence the leading 2. I also moved one factor of $\delta$ to the front, making all exponents of $\delta$ equal to the index of $g_n$ again. For a straight line, the sum is zero and $\vec{c_0'} = \lVert \vec{V_s} \rVert^2$ the square of the velocity at $t=s$.

The total chord length then can be found by summing $(15)$ for all values of $s$ involved. Let $\delta = \frac{1}{2N}$ for some positive integer $N$, the number of pieces we will cut the curve into. Then we need $N$ values of $s$:
$$s = (2k + 1)\delta \qquad\text{ for } k = \mathbin{{0}{...}{N}{-}{1}}$$

and
$$\begin{aligned}chord\_length &= 2 \delta \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \sqrt{c_0'^{(s)}} \left( 1 + \sum_{even\ n\geq 2}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^n}{n(n+1)}g_n^{(s)} \right) \\
&= 2 \delta \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \sqrt{c_0'^{(s)}}
 + 2 \delta \sum_{even\ n\geq 2}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^n}{n(n+1)} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} g_n^{(s)} \end{aligned} \tag{16}$$

Recall that the $g_n$ are a function of the $d_i$ which in turn are a function of the $c_i'$ which are polynomials in $s$ (hence the notation $g_n^{(s)})$ with coefficients $c_i$, where $s = (2k + 1)\delta$. Since $\delta$ is a known, fixed constant, the second term of equation $(16)$ is a multivariate polynomial in the $c_i$.

The first term contains the $\sqrt{c_0'^{(s)}}$, which will carry over to a lot of other terms after squaring the length; but is still straightforward to differentiate. Note that $c_0'$ is the square of the velocity at $t=s$, so that if we make $N$ arbitrary large (causing $\delta$ to go to zero) the first sum turns into the original integral (equation $(4)$).

At this point I feel like giving up though: assuming I can come up with a differentiable equation for the bending energy part, I am starting to think this is going to be a dead-end. In order to calculate the ideal curve I'd have to minimize the energy of the *whole* curve, all Bézier curves combined, where one curve influences the next only due to the demand that the curve must have $G_1$ continuity.

Am I right to give up, or does anyone have an idea that can be done in a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but far too long for a comment. A few remarks …

1. Minimizing arclength seems like a strange thing to do. It will cause your curve to become nearly piecewise linear, which is probably not what you want.
2. Estimating the integral by using a Taylor expansion is not a very good approach. There are many better methods of [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).
3. If you describe your objective (i.e. what you mean by “ideal”), I might be able to suggest other geometric characteristics of the curve that you could optimize. Lots of people have tried minimizing various forms of bending energy.
4. You might be better off using a b-spline representation of the curve. This will enforce certain continuity constraints that you probably care about. If you just use independent Bézier curves, you will have to add a lot of continuity constraints into your optimization problem.
5. I assume that you’ll end up passing the problem to some standard optimization package. To do this, you don’t need a mathematical **formula** for arclength, you just need a software function that will compute its numerical value on demand. I suggest thinking more like a programmer, and less like a mathematician.

Short answer … no, I don’t think you should give up. This seems like a solvable problem, to me.

If you decide that writing your own code is not worth the effort, there are plenty of spline fitting packages available. [Here is one](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/BSplineCurveLeastSquaresFit.pdf). I have never used it, but I have great respect for its author.

Comment: Thanks. 1. it is a balance between minimizing arc length (stretching energy, which is proportional with the square of the arc length) and the bending energy. If you don't care about the bending energy then yes you will get something nearly piecewise linear, which is exactly what you want in that case. The strange thing here is not taking bending energy into account.
2. The reason I tried a Taylor series is because this gives me a formula for the arc length that I can differentiate, which is necessary for the Euler-Lagrange equation to be used. By picking a sufficiently large N the

Comment: approximation if good enough. The problem is that to actually plug this into Euler-Lagrange it gets exponentially more complex after what I already have. Too complex; so this approach (including the Taylor series) is probably a dead end. I have numerical integration already working (using Gauss-Kronrod) which gives me the arc length to 15 decimal places for any cubic Bezier; but that is not enough to use Euler-Lagrange.

Comment: 3. I want to draw a smooth looking curve through given data points, using piece cubic Bezier curves for each pair of data point (they are ordered) such that the curve has G₁ continuity (no kinks). I found articles and code for C₁ continuity, but that is too restrictive and therefore possibly doesn't give the most optimal curve: I want to minimize the stretching and bending energy, not achieve C₁ continuity, which isn't related to that, at all (C₁ being that the velocity is continuous, the derivative with respect to the parameter t; t is NOT time and I'm not animating anything -- I am just

Comment: concerned with the shape.
4. See 3.

Comment: 5. No? The goal was to use Euler-Lagrange to find the piece-wise cubic Bezier curves that minimize the total energy of the whole curve (through all data points) where that total energy is the sum of the square the arc lengths of each piece PLUS some factor times the integral of the square of the curvature over the whole thing. By changing this factor I'd be able to change the curve from piece-wise straight lines to something with the lowest bending energy (but arbitrary length). I believe this has never been done before(?) and the reason is probably because it is way too hard?

Comment: Look up Nielsen's  "nu-splines". These are polynomial versions of some earlier "spline under tension" objects. The "tension" parameter lets you adjust between a piecewise linear shape and a curvier one.

Comment: Any G1 curve can be made C1 just by adjusting parameter ranges. Not much difference.

Comment: Don't understand your comment about numerical integration. Even if you had a formula for arclength, you'd be lucky if it gave you answers to better than 15 digits (using standard double-precision floating point arithmetic, anyway).